# Is there something special in range(start, stop, step).count(item)

Tags: count, python-3.x

I just discovered the py3k `range` method `count()`:

```
counts = range(start, stop, step).count(item)
```

Is not the result of the method always 1 or 0 ?. It seems to me a bit overkilling to call the method `count` (instead of maybe `contains`).

Is there something in this method that makes it different to the good old:

```
if item in range(start, stop, step)  ?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`range.count()` indeed always returns 0 or 1, and it's the same as `int(item in range(...))`.  Its main purpose is to make the interface of `range()` objects comply with the interface of a [`collections.abc.Sequence`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/collections.html#abcs-abstract-base-classes), which requires a `count()` method.

Note that `issubclass(range, collections.abc.Sequence)` returns `True`.